# $.when() : how to use it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have something like this :

```
fun1: function (){
    var jqXHR = $.get(
            "http://url.com",
             "search=toto",
            function(){});

    jqXHR.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       //do something
    });

    jqXHR.done(function (data,textStatus,jqXHR){
        //do something
    });
}

fun2: function (){
    fun1();
    //do something AFTER my AJAX requests are finished
}
```

I want to wait for my AJAX resquests are finished before continuing. To achieve this, I would normally use a callback function in fun1(). But my code now contains several levels of callbacks, and it looks messy. Then, I'd like to use the `$.when` method, but I don't know how to do that : as `fun1` is not a deferred object, I can't just write :

```
$.when(fun1()).then(//do something);
```

Comment: Did you look at the examples on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$.when` is mostly useful when you are waiting for *multiple* promises. It does not seem like you need it in your situation.

Here you just have to return the `jqXHR` object from the function:

```
fun1: function (foo){
    // ...
    return jqXHR;
}

fun2: function() {
    fun1().then(function() {
        // ...
    });
}
```

The object returned by `$.get` implements the promise interface, so you can directly attach callbacks to it. The documentation also provides a couple of examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return the Deferred object (or, better yet, is `promise()`) from `fun1()`.

Otherwise, you have no way of knowing when it will be finished.

Once you do that, you don't need to acll `$.when()`; instead, you can simply call `fun1().then(...)`